# Is there a gedit plugin that will detect errors in php code?

Tags: php, gedit, plugins, debugging

I dont know if this is even possible inside of gedit, i know there are third party editors that will do this but i like gedit and would like to know if anyone knows of such a plugin because i cant find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, phplint . You can get it from :

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/ThirdPartyPlugins-v3.0

Direct link https://github.com/janpecha/gedit-phplint

> To install one of these plugins, you need to download the files and put them in your ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/ directory (which may need to be created). They need to be in that exact directory; subdirectories are not scanned for plugins.

so ..

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/
```

Then on the second link I gave you, click the "Download Zip" button on the left , unzip the archive to `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/`

Comment: cool, i had to change the .plugin file from python to python3 to get it to enable in gedit, however when i run open gedit in the command line to test it, it gives me this error 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/share/gedit/plugins/phplint.py", line 59, in on_document_saving
    self.run_phplint()
  File "/home/user/.local/share/gedit/plugins/phplint.py", line 67, in run_phplint
    pos = errors.find('on line')
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API' which looks like the plugin is running the error. also note that this only occurs when testing.

Comment: fixed the error in the plugin, and that created a new error! Its not worth all this trouble. Now that i know '$php -l file.php' checks for errors im just going to type that in manually. Thanks for your help bodhi.zazen